# Google sheet script submit specific value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to send form details to a google sheets script working. Currently the following code submits a form field to a google sheet perfectly.

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

But I'm trying to only submit a specific field value, and if submitted, only once. So it would error if it existed in the google sheet. I can't figure it out.

Here is the JS

```
const scriptURL = 'HIDDEN'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
const loading = document.querySelector('.js-loading')
const successMessage = document.querySelector('.js-success-message')
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.js-error-message')

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      showLoadingIndicator()
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
        .then(response => showSuccessMessage(response))
        .catch(error => showErrorMessage(error))
    })

    function showLoadingIndicator () {
      form.classList.add('is-hidden')
      loading.classList.remove('is-hidden')
    }

    function showSuccessMessage (response) {
      console.log('Submitted', response)
      setTimeout(() => {
        successMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }

    function showErrorMessage (error) {
      console.error('Error!', error.message)
      setTimeout(() => {
        errorMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
      <input name="code" type="text" placeholder="Enter Code" required>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div class="loading js-loading is-hidden">
      <div class="loading-spinner">
        <svg><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="js-success-message is-hidden">You're not a winner, better luck next time.</p>
    <p class="js-error-message is-hidden">Error: Something wen't wrong, please try again later.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `But I'm trying to only submit a specific field value, and if submitted, only once. So it would error if it existed in the google sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Certainly, so we have a form. Lets say you can only submit the value 123 in the input field. And if the value 123 already exists in the google spreadsheet, it should return an error.

Comment: Do you want to search `123` in the whole sheet or in a certain column? Can you give a sample of the content of `newRow`? Does it contain only `123` or more data?

Comment: Only in a certain column, lets say the 2nd column. It contains only 123. So specifically that string.

Comment: If `newRow` contains only one value, this would mean that `newRow.length=1` and that this value will be set into column 1 (`getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length)`). Does it make sense to compare the content with column 2?

Comment: timestamp gets put into column 1, and then the form field gets put into column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you want to check for duplicates for the content of `newRow[1]` in column 2:**

- Retrieve the values from column B and convert them into a 1D array with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- Verify with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) either the content of `newRow` is already contained in column B (`indexOf()` will return `-1` if a value is not contained in an array)

**A sample where `newRow[1]` was manually set to `123` for testing purposes:**

```
function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    newRow[1] = 123;
    var columnTwo = sheet.getRange(1,2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
    if (columnTwo.indexOf(newRow[1]) == - 1){
      sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])      
      return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

UPDATE

`indexOf()` only works correctly for values of the same content AND data type.

If your spreadsheet values are numbers, but the incoming posted value is recognized string, you need to convert it to a number for correct comparison. This can be done by comparing with
`if (columnTwo.indexOf(Number(newRow[1])) == - 1){...`

Comment: Hmm, the form is still sending the data to the spreadsheet and applying a new row even if it's a duplicate in column B.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without having your data. Can you log `newRow` and prodive its content? (Also: the line `newRow[1] = 123;` is for testing when running the code manually from the script editor, once you test by submitting a real form - remove this line).

Comment: I did remove the newRow[1] = 123 and sorry I'm not sure how to log the code for you when I'm running it from a form on a website.

Comment: Implement before the line `sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]) `  `console.log(newRow)` and after you submit you from and `doPost` is called - go from the Apps Script editor on `View-Executions` to view your executions and corresponding logs.

Comment: I have a doPost trigger set up, but it's not showing in my View-Executions, it only shows my initialSetup execution

Comment: I assume then the WebApp is not deployed as "You". What is the content of the newly added line in the spreadsheet? Can you incorporate the line `Browser.msgBox(newRow[1])` into your code and provide the output?

Comment: It just continues to add in a new row with a timestamp in column a, and 123 in column b.

Comment: So the it does not show the messaeg box? Did you publish the WebApp as a NEW version after incorporating the changes?

Comment: But did you depploy the WebApp as a `New` version? Otherwise changes won't get saved.

Comment: Yes I did save, then redeployed as web app as new version. Still nothing. Just adds in the row as before.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the spreadsheet with aatched script for troubleshooting?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bQlrlp9Ri_-3OANUjDbuyy6U9RhwsU7uGzjqEUKVBo/edit?usp=sharing

The .gs code is the script I shared in initial question, with your changes.

Comment: Thanks! What about the html part to reproduce your html form and test submitting?

Comment: That is also in the original question, the js. Otherwise its just a standard html form submit

Comment: Added HTML form to the question too

Comment: With your form I found the error source: It is posting `123` as a string while the values in the sheet are numbers. `indexOf()` will only work correctly if the datatype is the same. You can solve the problem by using `if (columnTwo.indexOf(Number(newRow[1])) == - 1){...`

Comment: Ah lovely! It works now, thank you so much for your patience. How would I then send an error state to send a specific message for that error.

Comment: Thanks again.

So I actually do want an error to pass of some sort. As I only want the user to input a code once. 

So if they input 123, and try again. It should show an error saying 'already redeemed' or something?

Comment: I am afraid for passing data back to clientside you would need to take a completely different approach.  Your best bet would probably be a WebApp where the data is not posted but passed from client-side to serverside with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), which would allow you to pass (with success handler) data (or message) from serverside back to clientside. You could repeat this "pingpong" as often as needed.

Comment: Hmm possibly, I know this is an unorthodox set up but I'm working within the constraints I've been given. Thank you for your help though.